Formbuilder: User select 'Email' --> Empty / Not Empty
I have build Search Kit with a list of members who need to renew their membership.
The list contains contact data and email address.
In the form I want to have the option to select all members that DO have an email address (because then I can send them a renewal email) and all members that do NOT have an email address (they receive a letter).
I can't find the option for a user to select 'Email' is empty / not empty. When I choose Email ID as a filter field, I can not find an option / operator to get this in the form.
Is there a way that I can have the users filter on the Email field? See attachment 


Empty / not empty is not available as an exposed filter for SK but would be a great addition!
As a workaround, expose the email filter operator so it’s set to user select -

You can then use the Contains and Doesn’t Contain operators with “%” to find members who do and do not have an email address.


Sorry for my late reply (holiday). Good option. Thanks!
In my situationt the 'Contains' % gives the correct result.
The 'Doesn't Contain %, gives no results.
might be my installe. Thanks for now.

Updated civi to 5.77 and now it is working as above. Still not very userfriendly, but functioning. thanks!

You can use SearchKit to find contacts without an email by doing this

Does that help?

Not sure why you need this as part of Form Builder - if it is in SK then you can presumably set up two searches, one that finds those with no emails, and one that finds those that have emails.

Thanks for that. Yes I know this option. However, I want to use 1 search kit for multiple searches. So create 1 membership report and that CiviCRM users can then filter (depending on the context) on all memberships with a certain status AND email address. Or all Members with a certain membership type, and certain end date AND an email address.
Then, depending on their needs, the CiviCRM user can decide which filters to set in the form and then which actions to perform. That way we use the flexibility of SK and Forms in CiviCRM.
Does that clarify?

NB: I used previously also the Search Builder, where there is the option to choose 'Email is empty' (see attachment). That's the one I am looking for as a filter in the form builder.
